# Can't seem to get socket io to display any emits

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, io

I've been trying to figure out why I can't get any emits to show up in my terminal and it seems that everything is running fine.... except for seeing the emits. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// Create a new Express application
var app = express();

var views = path.join(process.cwd(), 'views');
app.use("/static", express.static("public"));

// Create an http server with Node's HTTP module. 
// Pass it the Express application, and listen on port 3000.
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ' + 3000)
});

// Instantiate Socket.IO hand have it listen on the Express/HTTP server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var game = require('./game');

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(views, 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    io.emit('connection', { message: "You are connected!" });
    game.initGame(io, socket);
    socket.emit('connected', { message: "You are connected!" });
    io.sockets.emit('test', 'test')
});
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emits are not automatically printed. `socket.emit` will send a message back to the client, not to the terminal. Use `console.log("whatever")` to print to the terminal:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Client connected');
    socket.on('test', function(data) {
        console.log("Got message of type 'test'containing data:", data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! I guess I got confused because in a demo game featuring socket io I got from github. The emits printed in the terminal with console.logs. However it also said "info - socket io started" when I opened the port. And I can't seem to do that with my project. Maybe it has to do something with that.

Comment: They might have activated the [debugging features](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/) of Socket.IO.